# How to enable remote extension in Chromium

Tags: chromium

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Chromium 58.

I am trying different solution to enable remote extensions but without success.

I tried to add CHROMIUM_FLAGS='--enable-remote-extensions'
 in /etc/environment but fails.

Can someone give me a solution?

I am newbie in Ubuntu.